# How to log out securely?

Tags: discussion, bug

I was using stackoverflow from my friends laptop. When I finished I logged out. But when I was logging in again and clicked "log in with stackexchange" it didn't ask me for password and logged me in automatically. I even tried clearing cookies and disconnecting-reconnecting internet connection (to changes IP), but it always login without asking for password or username.

How does stackoverflow identifies my account from my friends laptop? How can I reset it so that it does not log me in without username and password?

Comment: Logging out of Stack Overflow doesn't log you out of your chosen OpenId provider. You need to log out of **both**.

Comment: As sir Oded said , If you login with facebook , you also need to logout facebook . As others too. :)

Comment: @Cataclysm But arya said that he had cleared cookies :-(

Comment: @I don't like coding , don't be angry :). smile with love. Yes , after cleared cache I think he checked remember on facebook login page and as he said he only cleaned browser's caches and cookies.

Comment: @Idon'tlikecoding: The OP probably just cleared StackOverflow cookies, not _all_ cookies.

Comment: Acctually  @Oded is correct I have to to log out openid.stackexchange.com.